# How to permanently install an app in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, installation, apk

`npm start`

`Select a - for android`

However, with this, you only have the app running temporarily and have to do it repeatedly to launch it.

Is there a way to permanently install an app by **Build -> Install** like on Android Studio?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you wish to permanently install the app on your phone, you will have to generate a production build (.apk file) and install it on your phone.

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Read [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) for more clearity regarding builds.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you want to install it to your physical device or not.

In android studio you can press "Build" in the menu and then select build variants, change "app" to release.

Similarly in xcode, you can select build configuration to be on release.

Then you just build the project and you will have a release version of the app on your phone.